# Schwarz Inequality Proof Using Dirac Notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space

I am trying to prove Schwarz Inequality by following QM book by R. Shankar. I got almost to the end where I am having trouble.

I have noticed that there are similar questions on this website, but no one provided the answer I am looking for.

I would greatly appreciate it if you can help me with the missing steps. Also, do point out if I have made any mistakes. Attached is what I have. Sorry for not typing it in LaTeX, I did this in a hurry.

Thank you for your time!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in Shankhar's Quantum Mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/533923/)

Comment: @ElliotYu Sorry, but this still did not complete my missing step.